# unexpected tcp link to rev.poneytelecom.eu when running pm2

Tags: security, pm2

Every time when I start a pm2 server. I can detect a constant data flow (40kb/s) to **rev.poneytelecom.eu**. Is this supposed to be normal behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection to rev.poneytelecom.eu is due to the pm2 Keymetrics link connection that is enabled.

To disable the connection run:
`pm2 link delete`